# Qual a diferença da querie com '(aspas) e sem '(aspas)?

Tags: php, mysql, query

Bom galera, eu quero saber qual a diferença de um valor envolvido com '(aspas) e de valor sem as '(aspas).

Ex:

```
SELECT * FROM dados WHERE nome = $nome (valor sem uso das aspas)
SELECT * FROM dados WHERE nome = '$nome' (valor com uso das aspas)
```

Comment: Será melhor se você exemplificar onde viu cada um.

Comment: Anderson, eu não vi em nenhum lugar, apenas estou com essa dúvida mesmo, já que eu uso as '(aspas) e não sei pra que serve.

Comment: Olá,se você usar sem aspas,só funcionará para números,no caso acima,como é texto,é necessário utilizar as aspas simples,para o banco entender aonde começa e termina o valor.Recomendo também que pesquisa sopre bind params,pois deste jeito,sua query não está protegida contra sql injection.

Comment: Então, no caso eu sou pentester (Segurança Ofensiva) e de um tempo para cá, estou estudando sobre desenvolvimento seguro(Segurança Defensiva). Eu estou agora estou testando exatamente o SQLInjection, e acabei ficando em dúvida do uso das aspas. Obrigado por esclarecer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provavelmente você está falando de uma consulta sql feita com php. Geralmente quando você usa valores do tipo string em consulta sql, elas devem estar entre aspas `'`, já valores númericos não necessitam. Exemplo com sql (consulta executada diretamente no banco):

```
SELECT * FROM dados WHERE nome = 'João' AND idade = 12;
```

Quando você escreve a consulta a partir de uma linguagem de programação, nem sempre será preciso colocar a aspa explicitamente. Por exemplo, em php, usando PDO, você pode fazer colocando a aspa explicitamente, ou usando o recurso de prepare statement para não utiliza-la.

Exemplo de uso de aspas:

```
$nome = 'João';

//ao colocar a variavel diretamente no meio da consulta, o valor da 
//da variavel nome não ficará entre aspas
//será algo como: SELECT * FROM dados WHERE nome = João AND idade = 12
$pdo->query("SELECT * FROM dados WHERE nome = $nome AND idade = 12");

//Enquanto o correto (sintaxe sql) devia ser
//SELECT * FROM dados WHERE nome = 'João' AND idade = 12
//que pode ser obtido assim
$pdo->query("SELECT * FROM dados WHERE nome = '$nome' AND idade = 12");

//embora a forma de concatenar as aspas possa variavel
//pode ser feito assim também (fazendo o escape da aspa com \)
$pdo->query(
'SELECT * FROM dados WHERE nome = \'' . $nome . '\' AND idade = 12');

//Ou você pode omitir a aspa usando prepare statement
$statement = $pdo->prepare(
'SELECT * FROM dados WHERE nome = :nome AND idade = :idade');
$statement->execute([':nome' => $nome, 'idade' => 20]);
```